# Updating to Corda Enterprise - should the web-server include CE as a dependency?

Tags: corda

When upgrading a CorDapp to Corda enterprise - is there anywhere that we should be substituting Corda Enterprise as a dependency instead of Corda OS.

In my current use case, this applies specifically to the Web Server using the Corda-RPC library. Right now the repo uses the OS version; if I'm upgrading the node should I be pointing to the ENT version? Are there any differences?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Corda Enterprise release process, we test that the Enterprise RPC client works with both OS and Enterprise nodes, and that is the supported configuration for Corda Enterprise.

We don't currently test the Corda OS RPC client against Corda Enterprise nodes (however the interfaces are the same so they *should* be compatible).

Additionally, the v3 OS RPC client is completely incompatible with V3 Enterprise and V4 OS and Enterprise nodes, due to a change in the serialization framework.